# Optimization on code generation for functors and lambdas

Tags: c++

Considering the choice between a functor and a lambda from performance perspective when I define a predicate for `std` algorithms. The code is on critical path and amount of data is large.

Looking into the generated [code](https://godbolt.org/z/njKMonqc3) for a simple case I see that there is no difference in the generated code for both cases, so nothing in the way of compiler to do its work on optimization.

But this is a simple case. The question is, is there a features of both approaches which could supreme one against another from the perspective of possible code optimization issues when it is compiled?

I know that all this is platform/compiler/task-depended, but is there something I could miss in overall approach that could hit me later?

The [code](https://godbolt.org/z/njKMonqc3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr auto check_for_fullstops_lm = []() {
    bool last_is_fullstop = false;
    return [last_is_fullstop](auto lhs, auto rhs) mutable {
        if (last_is_fullstop) {
            return false;
        }

        last_is_fullstop = lhs == '.' || rhs == '.';

        return lhs == rhs;
        };
    };

struct check_for_fullstops {
    bool last_is_fullstop = false;

    bool operator ()(auto lhs, auto rhs) {
        if (last_is_fullstop) {
            return false;
        }

        last_is_fullstop = lhs == '.' || rhs == '.';

        return lhs == rhs;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::string text1 = "This is text. First man.";
    std::string text2 = "This is text. First woman.";

    auto pos = std::mismatch(text1.begin(), text1.end(), text2.begin(), text2.end()).first - text1.begin();
    auto pos_lm = std::mismatch(text1.begin(), text1.end(), text2.begin(), text2.end(), check_for_fullstops_lm()).first - text1.begin();
    auto pos_fn = std::mismatch(text1.begin(), text1.end(), text2.begin(), text2.end(), check_for_fullstops()).first - text1.begin();

    std::cout << "Position without predicate:" << pos 
        << "\nPosition with lambda:" << pos_lm
        << "\nPosition with functor:" << pos_fn << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why did you do lambda with mutable state? `std::mismatch` will stop as soon as predicate will return `false` so there is no point to remember that period was encountered earlier.

Comment: Why are you looking from the beginning of the text? Why not look from the back of the text forward and stop at the first `.`? E.g. use `text.rbegin()` and `text.rend()`?

Comment: @MarekR, can you show a way to implement this without mutable lambda? I slightly reworked the example in function `main` to show the purpose of the predicate and the difference. Does it covers your question?

Comment: Anyway do you have a proven performance issue and if so did you profile the code to find out the biggest bottleneck?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, (1) in real text there would be tons of full stops, so I need them in the order of appearance; (2) I was criticized many times for use of backward iterators where forward ones would do; they are much simpler to read in code and or large data they could be cache-friendlier. At the end of the day, this is just an example, could be any direction; would it affect the answer to the question?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, no I don't. My concern is that I don't want to put a time bomb in my code which will be harder to detect and eliminate later in case there are known issues from other people experience. I am just in two minds which approach to use and performance is one of the concerns. I don't want to skip something, that's why I am asking. When this code will be incorporated in the project later even with profiler it would be hard to say that exactly this code led to issue, since nobody will remember that this tiny piece of code could be implemented in another way.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, still curios how backward moving could help here. At the end of the day the goal is to cut sentences, delimited by periods, so they would frame the sentence from both sides. How back moving would help?

Comment: Maybe I was to focused on your example code, and misunderstood the splitting part.

Comment: But if cutting sentences is your problem... I usually use something like this : https://onlinegdb.com/qphCGC33b (should not be to hard to filter out empty sentences). No data will be copied, and there will be only one loop from start to end

Comment: Also my apologies if I added confusion to the discussion, that was not my goal ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, no worries, it really helps; you made me thinking if this could be generalized somehow. Actually, I have [tokenizer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289511/natural-language-text-fast-tokenizer-rev-5) and even [parser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289653/multithreaded-natural-language-text-parser-rev-3) for this purpose. (to be continued since comment's length is limited...)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, (...continue) My problem is slightly different since using large texts (gigabytes) I run expensive operations like [this one] (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289260/fast-search-for-the-longest-repeating-substrings-in-large-text-rev-4) where I need complex predicates to work on indexes (for more sophisticated requests) while text already compiled to lexem ids. For example, if I want this fast search find not sequences, but sentences limited by some delimiters I may use the same code with similar predicate.

Comment: Oh there are some pretty nifty large text search algorithms out there I remember reading some papers a long long time ago... but this really isn't my area of expertise.  I think the algorithm you use in the end is more important than optimizing a lambda (at least for now)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, sure. The goal of current question was just to avoid some possibly "common known" issues which could have led to problems or the later stages which would be hard to detect with performance analyses due to distributed effect of design choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lambda expression defines a unique, unnameable functor class, and instantiates it. There's no performance difference between that and writing out and instantiating an equivalent class yourself. They have the same observable behaviour, so the compiler is free to implement them in exactly the same way.

The syntax of lambda expressions was added not because it adds a new capability to the language, but because it abbreviates the existing capability in a tightly defined way

Comment: Yes, I see, but in this particular case functor looks even simpler, at least for people who accustomed to structures for years. My question is not focusing on the benefits from lambda (since as you have mentioned it was added later), my question is about the surrounding syntax sugar and if in some (obvious for somebody) cases it could be in a way of compiler to do its work on optimization. I got your answer that there are shouldn't be any issues for the compilers.

Comment: @DamirTenishev As the answer says, it defines a class type in a specific way. If you write an equivalent class, then the optimiser has the same input, thus you get the same output.